# SQL JOIN, GROUP BY on multiple tables to get TOP

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've inherited the following DB design. Tables are:

```
product
---------
product_id  
product_name
price
amountOfStock (pk)

component
--------
component_id  
component_name
category
amountOfStock (fk)
seller_no (pk)

seller
---------------
seller_no (fk)
seller_name 
seller_address
seller_phone
```

I want to get "the product which has the most number of sellers". What is its query? I use multiple joins so I didn't find the answer.

Comment: there is a not relation between `product` and  other two tables (`component` and `seller`). is `amountOfStock` is the common between `product` and `component` table?

Comment: @zealous I edited with fk's and pk's

Comment: I think `seller_no` should be the primary key of the `seller` table and foreign key in `component ` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, assuming there are no duplicates in `seller` table. if there are duplicates then do `count(distinct seller_no)`.

```
select
  product_id,
  product_name,
  count(seller_no) as total_sellers
from product p
join component c
on p.amountOfStock = c.amountOfStock

join seller s
on c.seller_no = s.seller_no

group by
  product_id,
  product_name

order by
  total_sellers desc

limit 1
```